# Как связать данные в Laravel?

Tags: mysql, база-данных, laravel

Как связать данные в Laravel?
Есть 3 таблицы:

1. Manufacturers
2. Collections
3. Colors

Эти таблицы используют отношение One To Many. У Manufacturer может быть много Collection. У Collection может быть много Color.

Как посчитать сколько коллекций принадлежит производителю и сколько всего цветов? Производитель 1 имеет 2 коллекции каждая из которых содержит по 10 цвет.

Желаемый результат:

1. Производитель 1
2. Коллекции 2
3. Цветов 20

Model, Controller и View. Остальное 2 идентичны.

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Manufacturer extends Model
{
    public function collections()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Collection');
    }
}
```

.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Admin;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Manufacturer;

class ManufacturerController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $manufacturers = Manufacturer::all();

        return view('admin.manufacturers.index', compact('manufacturers'));
    }
}
```

.

```
@extends('layouts.admin')

@section('content')
<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th scope="col">Производитель</th>
            <th scope="col">Коллекция</th>
            <th scope="col">Цвет</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
        @foreach ($manufacturers as $manufacturer)
            <td><a href="{{ route('manufacturers.edit', $manufacturer->id) }}">{{ $manufacturer->name }}</a></td>
            <td><a href="{{ route('collections.index', ['manufacturer' => $manufacturer->id]) }}">2</a></td>
            <td><a href="{{ route('colors.index', ['manufacturer' => $manufacturer->id]) }}">5</a></td>
        @endforeach
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
@endsection
```

Comment: https://laravel.ru/docs/v5/eloquent-relationships

Answer (score 1):

Посмотрите связь: [has-many-through](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through) возможно она наведет на решение.

Код примерный:

```
class Manufacturer extends Model
{
    public function colors()
    {
        return $this->hasManyThrough('App\Colors','App\Collection');
    }
}
```

Так же из задачи не понятно нужны уникальные цвета или нет, а это разные решения.

Ставить id производителя в таблицу цветов думаю плохая идея.

Если брать не связь, а решение конкретной задачи, то

1) Можно написать 2 запроса через queryBuilder на нахождение количества

2) Коллекции посчитать через Лара-коллекции, а цвета через  sql, что-то примерно:

```
$result = Manufacturer::with(['collections'=>function($query){
    $query->withCount('colors');
}])->get();

$collections = $result->pluck('collections')->collapse();
$collectionsCount = $collections->count();
$colorsCount = $collections->sum('colors_count');
```

Comment: Можете подробнее рассказать почему id производителя в таблице цветов это плохо? Логика такая: у одного производителя может быть много коллекций, в которые входят разные цвета (от этого производителя). У коллекции всегда один производитель, а у цвета всегда только одна коллекция. То есть, цвет может принадлежать только одному производителю и только одной коллекции. Коллекция может принадлежать только одному производителю. Производитель имеет много разных коллекций и много разных цветов. То есть, коллекция — это группа цветов определенного производителя.

Comment: @РодионПоляков ну это в целом ненужная связь просто. Это некая денормализация таблицы (что не есть плохо). В целом грубой ошибки нет. Вы денормализуете связи, что бы упроститить запросы к БД. Возможно такая предметная область, но в целом не понятно, почему у цвета один производитель. Цвет "белый" - и будет 10 разных белых цветов для каждого производителя и каждой коллекции?

Comment: Речь идёт о товарах для руководителя (нитки). Ареола (производитель) имеет акрил (коллекция) и полушерсть (коллекция). В обоих коллекциях есть белый (цвет), но по факту это разные нитки т.к отличаются составом (иногда могут и оттенком). Поэтому у производителя коллекции и цвета всегда уникальные. Вы предлагаете использовать ещё одну таблицу для связи? Я просто не очень понимаю принцип Вашего подхода. Плюс, Вы предлагаете отказаться от withCont()? Объясните пожалуйста.

Comment: @РодионПоляков Я показал один из примеров c withCount, причем там без дополнительного столбца. 
По поводу архитектуры: я бы в вашем случае сделал отдельную таблицу и сущность. Можно прямо так и назвать "нитки" и в ней ссылку на производителя, ссылку на коллекцию, ссылку на цвет. Но вообще предметная область может быть не так как я ее понимаю. Но куча белого цвета... ну так себе решение.

Comment: Идея с отдельной таблице "нитки" очень понравилась, спасибо. Где можно почитать про такой подход или может вы можете показать простой пример? Я вам буду очень благодарен. Извините, что я так тяжело "схватываю". Это мой первый проект. У цвета есть имя и фото, а на фото моток, а на мотке этикетка производителя. Цвет не может повторяться. Вот пример на рабочем сайте: https://anje.com.ua/yarn/igea/pushistyyi-moher-moonlight-550-m-34151/

Comment: @РодионПоляков хех. Посмотрел сайт... там не все так просто, как казалось... у вас там фильтр довольно мощный. Там и цвета, и тип и т.д. Я даже потерялся в совете))) Почитайте еще про EAV архитектуру для интернет магазинов. Возможно выход найдете там.